# How do I generate multiple, separate lists while iterating over dataframe column

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I am working with a data frame that has a column for time (in YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM/SS format) and another column for wind speeds- that were collected every second over the course of several months.

I want my code to generate lists that group all of the wind speed values to the day they were taken on.

```
day_number = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  #NOTE: I only run the if clause on the first 78450 rows of data
  #because I get an error from the last line of code
  if index < 78450:
    if time[index][0:10] == time[index+1][0:10]:
      #[here I want to generate lists grouping my wind speed values]
    else:
      day_number += 1
```

Is there a way to generate multiple lists from a single for loop?  Or is there a certain Pandas function that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a synthetic set of data using datetime and timedelta, so spread some values across a few days:

```
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(x*.5) for x in range(10)], 'wind_speed':[x for x in range(10)]})
```

df looks like:

```
    date                        wind_speed
0   2020-07-08 15:42:11.399609  1
1   2020-07-09 15:42:11.399609  2
2   2020-07-10 15:42:11.399609  3
3   2020-07-11 15:42:11.399609  4
4   2020-07-12 15:42:11.399609  5
5   2020-07-13 15:42:11.399609  6
6   2020-07-14 15:42:11.399609  7
7   2020-07-15 15:42:11.399609  8
8   2020-07-16 15:42:11.399609  9
9   2020-07-17 15:42:11.399609  10
```

Group by year, month, day of date column and apply list to `wind_speed`

```
df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month, df.date.dt.day])['wind_speed'].apply(list)
```

Output

```
date  date  date
2020  7     8          [1]
            9       [2, 3]
            10      [4, 5]
            11      [6, 7]
            12      [8, 9]
            13        [10]
```

To get rid of the multi-index

```
df.index.set_names(['year','month','day'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This looks much cleaner.